# Getting unique column amongst duplicate columns but returning the complete row

Tags: sql

I need help on creating a select statement in sql to get the unique rows.

I need the unique Reference ID but since Call Time is also unique, I only need to get the first row out of the similar rows.

I have this table[Calls]:

[image]

The result should be:

[image]

When I used:

> `Select Distinct * FROM Calls`

It will return the same table and not the result I want.

Comment: Which `database` you are using

Comment: @POHH for which *database*? Anyway, it sounds like a way to limit the results, not return distinct rows

Comment: The results aren't unique. They contain the earliest call time for each ReferenceID. That's grouping on ReferenceID and MIN on the other columns

Comment: What if the `Call Time` or `Number` columns are different in a `Reference ID`-group? Do you want to get an arbitryry record or the first according to the `Call Time`-column? By similar you mean the same day (so time truncated)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the desired results show the earliest call time but the same call number for each ID. I suspect that's what the OP means by "the first row"

Comment: Does a Refererence ID always have the same Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may helps you...
min(date) is the first datetime for each individual

```
Select referenceid,min(date),number  from calls
group by  referenceid,number
```

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned that   the `Number` column should be part of the `Group By`(_"unique `Reference ID` "_). If it's possible that there are multiple numbers per `ReferenceID` this yields the wrong result.

Comment: for each "ReferenceID"  there will be a unique "Number"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ReferenceID,
       MIN(CallTime) AS CallTime,
       MIN(Number) AS Number
FROM dbo.TableName t
GROUP BY ReferenceID
```